# Ext Js 4 - Change the order of files loading

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When my Ext Js application loads up, I get an error for a missing class. I checked the console's Net tab and found out that the files are loaded in wrong order. Meaning the class which requires another class to work is loaded after that class. Is there a way to change the loading order of files in Ext Js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`requires`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-requires) config in the depending class:

```
Ext.define('Depender', {
    requires: 'Dependee',

    // ...
});
```

This will tell the [loader](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Loader), that class `Dependee` must be loaded before class `Depender` can be instantiated.

Comment: I am already! I'm adding the require config with the class name, but it still fails somehow! I still see in the Net panel that the depender is loaded before the dependee.

Comment: That's not necessarily a problem, in fact, this is the expected behaviour. The framework does not know that `Depender` requires `Dependee` until it has loaded the class. Keep in mind that the required class is needed before **instantiation**, not before the class is loaded. Your error is probably related to something else. Can you post your code and the exact error message?

Comment: Actually, I found out that the issue was never caused by loading order. I had to pass the function name as a string to the store, but as a variable to the model. Solved! Thanks!